# How do I get DateTimeFormat working with Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a controller method that looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(headers = "Accept=application/json;charset=utf-8", value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public Blah test(@ModelAttribute MyObject parms, HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception { 

        // blah blah
    }
```

MyOBject looks like this:

```
public class MyObject{

    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)
    private Calendar someDate;
    // blah blah setters getters
```

When I call this method via browser like so:

```
http://localhost:8080/blah/test?someDate=2011-07-11T21%3A28%3A59.564%2B01%3A00
```

I am getting Error 400 - Bad Request.

I kept trying with various different values for someDate (always using a URL encoder to encode the special chars) and nothing works.
All the ones I tried (pre-URL encoding):

2000-10-31 01:30:00.000-05:00

2011-07-11T21:28:59.564+01:00

2014-04-23T13:49:28.600Z

I know dates dont match I am merely trying to get Spring to parse this damn date for me into that Calendar object!! (Though really I would prefer it was a java.sql.Timestamp but that's probably even harder to get done)

How do I do this?

Am I writing the date wrong? 
Am I using the wrong annotation for properties in a ModelAttribute (Note I have many other parameters so I bundle them up in a ModelAttribute object, dont want to use @RequestParm)

The error that shows up in log file:

```
Field error in object 'myObject' on field 'someDate': rejected value [2011-07-11T21:28:59.564+01:00]; codes [typeMismatch.myObject.someDate,typeMismatch.someDate,typeMismatch.java.util.Calendar,typeMismatch]; arguments [org.springframework.context.support.DefaultMessageSourceResolvable: codes [myObject.someDate,someDate]; arguments []; default message [someDate]]; default message [Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Calendar' for property 'someDate'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type java.lang.String to type @org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat java.util.Calendar for value '2011-07-11T21:28:59.564+01:00'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to parse '2011-07-11T21:28:59.564+01:00']
```

Comment: If you turn your logs to DEBUG, Spring will tell you the issue.

Comment: Your first test works for me.

Comment: How is it possible it works for you? I am adding the error in my log file to the end of my OP (too long to put in comment)

Comment: What Spring version are you using? If the date is well URL encoded, this should work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This

```
'2011-07-11T21:28:59.564+01:00'
```

value is incorrect since the expected format is

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ
```

you can't have a `:`  inside the `+0100` timezone offset.

You must be url encoding it wrong.

Comment: Yup that's the problem! I put the colon in there thinking I needed it. Thanks for catching that!!

Comment: @Sotirios has great attention. This site misleads http://www.captaindebug.com/2011/08/using-spring-3-datetimeformat.html#.U1jHpPmSx4g

Comment: The example in the `ISO.DATE_TIME` documentation has a colon in the offset which mislead me too.