# Date as a request parameter in Spring REST

Tags: java, spring, rest, date, spring-boot

My controller looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/process_date", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity processDate
       (@RequestParam(value = "time", required = false) 
        @DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX") Date date){
// process the date
}
```

The POSTMAN query:

```
http://localhost:8080/process_date?date=2014-05-09T00:48:16-04:00
```

It's giving me `IllegalArgumentException`. The full exception is:

```
{
  "timestamp": 1495736131978,
  "status": 400,
  "error": "Bad Request",
  "exception": "org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException",
  "message": "Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.util.Date'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam @org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat java.util.Date] for value '2013-05-10T07:48:16-04:00'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern component: XXX",
  "path": "/airspaces"
}
```

Now, strangely when I run:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX");
try {
    System.out.println(df.parse("2013-05-10T07:48:16-04:00"));
} catch (ParseException e) {
    System.out.println("PARSE EXCEPTION!!!");
}
```

It works without any exception. Same date-format, same date.

One workaround would be to receive the date as a string and then do the conversions through the parser method.

But I'm concerned more about what's going on behind the scene here.

Comment: It's probably because converter and formatter are 2 different things. Have you already checked this thread: http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web/86986-datetimeformat-for-pathvariable-not-converting ?

Answer (score 1):

yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX

USE:

yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX     >>>  2017-05-04T12:08:56.235-07:00

S          Millisecond 
X         Time zone
ISO 8601 time zone  -07; -0700; -07:00

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `Z` instead of `XXX` in your pattern. It should works.

Comment: It'll work, but it won't allow me to send the timezone.

Comment: It will allow if you remove semicolon in timezone, use `-0400` instead of `-04:00` in your request. Check this post please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23251895/how-do-i-get-datetimeformat-working-with-spring-mvc.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you change to `@RequestParam(value = "date", required = false)`, as the parameter `value` is not the same as your URL parameter name which you are using in Postman.

Also looking at your logs, you're using `java.util.Date`. Have you considered using new Java 8 API, `java.time.LocalDate` instead ?